# Force Close of app Error on running Android Emulator

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

This is my first Android application which I am learning using the official tutorials at  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/ and
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/
I've followed the tutorial step by step included by app_id, Hash keys, refrenced libraries but as soon as the application is launched on the emulator there is an error of force close application.
my logcat is as follows

```
    10-16 20:48:13.169: D/AndroidRuntime(639): Shutting down VM
10-16 20:48:13.169: W/dalvikvm(639): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
10-16 20:48:13.229: E/AndroidRuntime(639): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 20:48:13.229: E/AndroidRuntime(639): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.facebook.myagent.MyAgent: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.myagent.MyAgent in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.facebook.myagent-2.apk]
10-16 20:48:13.229: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.makeApplication(ActivityThread.java:649)
10-16 20:48:13.229: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4232)
10-16 20:48:13.229: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3000(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-16 20:48:13.229: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2071)
10-16 20:48:13.229: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-16 20:48:13.229: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-16 20:48:13.229: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-16 20:48:13.229: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-16 20:48:13.229: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-16 20:48:13.229: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-16 20:48:13.229: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-16 20:48:13.229: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-16 20:48:13.229: E/AndroidRuntime(639): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.myagent.MyAgent in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.facebook.myagent-2.apk]
10-16 20:48:13.229: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
10-16 20:48:13.229: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
10-16 20:48:13.229: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
10-16 20:48:13.229: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:942)
10-16 20:48:13.229: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.makeApplication(ActivityThread.java:644)
10-16 20:48:13.229: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  ... 11 more
10-16 20:48:15.449: I/Process(639): Sending signal. PID: 639 SIG: 9
```

Comment: did you refer to the facebook sdk library in your android project?

Comment: yah I did refer to facebookk sdk as per tutorial

Comment: Its path is MyAgent>>Properties>>Android>>Reference>>Facebook SDK

Answer (score 0):

You have an uncouth exception.
The problem is that one thread can't handle the UI and the background operations from Facebook.
either add another Thread that only execute the web/Facebook stuff.
or use the AsyncTask, with is the best practice in this situation.
check thsi tutorial out: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVaGZwuYmck

Comment: in that case op would be getting `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. I don't see that in the stacktrace. Your post does not answer the question